# Request specific challenge with ACME client library

Tags: python, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

How to request specific challenge (`TLSSNI01`) from the server?

Currently only `DNS01`, `HTTP01`, `TLSALPN01` are returned and I don't see any place where it could be specified by reading https://acme-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: `TLS-ALPN-01` was drafted in fact ( still not a full standard) to replace `TLS-SNI-01` after discovery of problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tls-sni-01 challenge has been removed because of security issues.

Comment: For the curious, the details on `TLS-SNI-01` vulnerabilities and how they were (ab)used are at https://labs.detectify.com/2018/01/12/how-i-exploited-acme-tls-sni-01-issuing-lets-encrypt-ssl-certs-for-any-domain-using-shared-hosting/ with in it: *TL;DR: I was able to issue SSL certificates I was not supposed to be able to. AWS CloudFront and Heroku were among the affected. The issue was in the specification of ACME TLS-SNI-01 in combination with shared hosting providers.* The vulnerability is in fact not internal of the method, but when used on shared hosting.